# Hibernate: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My problem is:

**NOW MY SPRING-CFG.xml looks like this**
spring-cfg.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <bean id="dataSource" 
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
            p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" 
            p:url="jdbc:h2:~/test"
            p:username="sa" 
            p:password="sa"/>


        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="mappingResources" value="/WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property>


        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>


        <bean id="userManagerDAOImpl" class="app1.persistance.UserManageDAOImpl">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>




        <bean id="userManagerServiceImpl" class="app1.service.UserManageServiceImpl">
            <property name="userManageDAOIF" ref="userManagerDAOImpl"/>
        </bean>

        <import resource="spring-security.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Exception:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springConf/spring-cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2257)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2229)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2209)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2162)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2113)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 25 more

апр 15, 2015 3:21:52 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springConf/spring-cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2257)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2229)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2209)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2162)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2113)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 25 more

апр 15, 2015 3:21:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springConf/spring-cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: /WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2257)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2229)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2209)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2162)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2113)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 25 more
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>

       <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> 

        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="/WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My project srtucture:

[image: Structure]

Can Understand what is the problem. 
And Also sometimes I seee exception like ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition. Is all related to this issue?
What is the problem?

Comment: Remove the `<mapping` element from your hibernate configuration file and only leave it in the spring configuration.

Comment: When I did that it says lass path resource [WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Thank you Sir for your descriptive answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both configured the mapping resources in Spring and in your hibernate configuration file. Also you current configuration breaks proper transaction management for Spring.

I strongly suggest to remove your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and move everything into your spring configuration.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources" value="/WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Your `transaction` and `connection` properties in the configuration are useless due to the injection of the `DataSource` the `current_session_context` fiddling would break proper tx management. With above configuration you can remove your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Comment: Still have same problem as above. I changed my spring-cfg.xml as you said, but still have same problem with Can'\t find mappings

Answer (score 1):

As per the the documentation

```
 Set Hibernate mapping resources to be found in the class path,
 like "example.hbm.xml" or "mypackage/example.hbm.xml".
```

Hence you cannot use

```
<property name="mappingResources" value="/WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml" />
```

You should use `mappingLocations` and path should not start with /WEB-INF it should be relative path.

```
Set locations of Hibernate mapping files, for example as classpath
resource "classpath:example.hbm.xml". Supports any resource location
via Spring's resource abstraction, for example relative paths like
"WEB-INF/mappings/example.hbm.xml" when running in an application context.
```

Hence your property should be mappingLocations with value as relative path as shown below.

However I would suggest you to move all your configurations to src/main/resources directory. During war generation, maven plugin would copy this src/main/resources directory to /WEB-INF/classes directory which is the classpath and use can refer all the files using class-path. which is nice and cleaner approach compared to the above one.

For example you can place `App1User.hbm.xml` inside `src/main/resources/hibernatConf` directory. During war generation the file will be copied to `{context path}/WEB-INF/classes/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xm`l and you can refer it as shown below.

```
 <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Bu default spring try to find the path with class-path as parent directory....so you should use your directory in that way....Also you dont need to mapping in hibernate cfg file if you have already definded it in spring cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

in the

```
<property name="mappingResources" value="/WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml" />
```

try this:

```
<property name="mappingResources" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/hibernateConf/App1User.hbm.xml" />
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Just moved my App1User.hbm.xml to folder where spring-cfg.xml is. Thank you for your help